# React functional component able to change its state, is possible?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a React component for a Dialog.
I want to use Bootstrap Modal component.
I use TypeScript.

This is the usage I plan to use:

```
<Dialog icon="edit" title="Edit the item" buttons={...} onSave={...} >
... put here the content of the dialog
</Dialog>
```

Now, I started to write the code to make the Modal visible (pseudo-code):

```
interface Props {
  // open by:
  buttonText: OpenIcons,

  title: string,
  isOpen?: boolean
}

export const Dialog:FC<Props> = (props) => {
  let {buttonText, title, isOpen, children} = props

  return <> 
    {button && <button className="btn btn-sm">{buttonText}}</button> }

    { isOpen && <div>
      {title}
      <div>{children}</div>
      <buttons>...</buttons>
    </div>
    }
  </>
}
```

The problem is: how can I manage to change the *isOpen* property to *true* and made the *Dialog* component reflect this state?
Yes, I can use another component in the page (button text, icon, link...) that manage to change that state and pass it to the Dialog component, but I don't want to.
I want the *Dialog* component to self-manage its icon/button/link trigger.
The only solution I can think about is create another component inside the *Dialog* component, **a sort of wrapper**.
It has to manage the *DialogButton* (or whatever) and a new *DialogInternal* component that are not exported, so that the developer just see the exorted *Dialog* component.
I hope this idea is clear.

There is any better way (simpler, cleaner) to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code using a useState hook

```
export const Dialog:FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  let {buttonText, title, children} = props
  
  const handleClick = () => setOpen(!open);

  return <> 
    {button && <button className="btn btn-sm" onClick={handleClick}>{buttonText}}</button> }

    { open && <div>
      {title}
      <div>{children}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Close</button>
    </div>
    }
  </>
}
```

Comment: You should post the code on this site. You can still link to code externally but external links tend to not last so post the relevant code in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react hooks like `useState` and `useEffect` for maintaining a state in functional components

Ex:
for Usestate

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(initial value);
```

for useEffect

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[dependencies]);
```